# How to use ESP32 to generate HDMI

Tags: esp32

*hi,*
me and my friend are making a console and we would like it to output HDMI(preferably 1080p) using ESP32 but, after looking for ages we haven't found **anything**.

Answer (score 1):

You can get a [VGA card](https://bitluni.net/esp32-vga) for it, but that is probably the limit of what can be achieved in terms of processing power.

However, it should be sufficient for retro-style consoles. For anything more, you'd need more powerful hardware.

Comment: ok. do you know of any FPGA's that might work?

Answer (score 1):

See this image to connect ESP32 to VGA:

[image: ESP32 to VGA]

You then need to add VGA to HDMI Converter.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you can produce video with the ESP.  Look into what Bitluni has done.  Also, there is others that have produced code for emulators all on the ESP32 with composite video and VGA outputs.
Youtube search for bitluni, or  "esp32 composite video"

I have built several ESP32 clocks out of CRT TVs (color and black/white).

Answer (score -2):

The ESP32 does not produce video output of any kind. Have a look at the [data sheet](https://www.espressif.com/sites/default/files/documentation/esp32_datasheet_en.pdf)